# 500 TypeError: Object #<IncomingMessage> has no method 'csrfToken'

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to add csrf protection to my Nodejs app using Express.
When i add this midlleware :

```
 app.use(function (req, res, next) {  
    res.locals.csrftoken = req.csrfToken();
});
```

i get this error :

```
500 TypeError: Object #<IncomingMessage> has no method 'csrfToken'
```

Someone can help me resolve this.

Here is my app.js code :

```
var express = require('express')


     , routes = require('./routes') 
      , http = require('http')
      , path = require('path');

     var app = express();

     app.configure(function () {
        app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
        app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
        app.set('view engine', 'jade');
        app.use(express.favicon());
        app.use(express.logger('dev'));

        app.use(express.bodyParser());
        app.use(express.cookieParser());
        app.use(express.session({ secret: 'the secret' }));
        app.use(express.csrf());

     app.use(function (req, res, next) {  
            res.locals.csrftoken = req.csrfToken();
        });



    app.use(express.methodOverride());  
    app.use(app.router);


    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
});

app.configure('development', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler()); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

CSRF and other middleware except `static` are not bundled with express 4.x anymore - **my assumption is that you're using 4.x**

If your express version is 4.x, then you'll need to manually install [csurf](https://github.com/expressjs/csurf) and use that instead of `express.csrf()`

See more details about middleware https://github.com/senchalabs/connect?#middleware and changes explanation here http://expressjs.com/guide/using-middleware.html#middleware.built-in

**Later Edit:** For Express 3.x branch you will need a minimum version of **3.4.0** since `csrfToken()` method first appears in `express@3.4.0`, that being the package when `connect` was updated to `2.9.0` which is the first `connect` version to provide the `csrfToken` method.

Comment: Thank you, but i use Express 3, here is the dependencies section of my pachage.json file : "dependencies": {
    "express": "~3.1.0",
    "jade": "*",
    "mysql": "^2.5.3",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "sequelize": "^2.0.0-rc2",
    "sequelize-cli": "^0.3.3",
    "validator": "^3.22.1"
  },

Comment: Thanks for the details regarding express version. I've updated my answer to cover 3.x as well.

Comment: LE: If you can't update to express@3.4.0 just use req.session._csrf